# Scale div to fit background image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image that I want to expand 100% width and auto scale the div to fit the required height of the image. At the moment it is not scaling the div height unless I set the height of the div to 100% but then it just stretches to the full height of the screen, whereas I want it to scale to the height of the image.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="mainHeaderWrapper">


</div><!--end mainHeaderWrapper-->
<br class="clear" />;
```

Here is the css:

```
    #mainHeaderWrapper{


     background: url(http://localhost/site/gallery/bg1.jpg);
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover; 
     background-size: 100% 100%;

     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center; 

 }

 .clear { clear: both; }
```

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: How about putting an `<img>` in the div.

Comment: I will try but is it not possible to achieve what i want through background in css?

Comment: You want the width to be 100% of the browser window but the height to be limited to the height of the image? Are the proportions of the image known/consistent?

Comment: No, there is no way to set the div size, to dynamically use the same dimensions of the background image, using only CSS. You either need to insert the background image as it's own image element or use Javascript to calculate the dimensions of the image and apply them to the div.

Comment: It sounds very much like you want the div to be a container that shows the image, right? If that is your purpose, use an img.

Comment: @MrLister Even if the image is not part of the page content? If it's a design element.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let a transparent image dictate the `DIV` dimensions.
Inside that div put the same image with CSS `opacity: 0`

```
<div id="mainHeaderWrapper">
   <img src="path/to/image.jpg"><!-- I'm invisible! -->
</div>
```

set that image to

```
#mainHeaderWrapper {
    background: no-repeat url(path/to/image.jpg) 50% / 100%;
}
#mainHeaderWrapper img {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%; /* max width */
    opacity: 0;  /* make it transparent */
}
```

That way the height of the DIV will be dictated by the containing invisible image, and having the `background-image` set to *center, full* (`50% / 100%`) it will match that image's proportions.

#### Need some content inside that DIV?

Due to the containing image, you'll need an extra child element that will be set to `position: absolute` **acting as an overlay element**

```
<div id="mainHeaderWrapper">
   <img src="path/to/image.jpg"><!-- I'm invisible! -->
   <div>Some content...</div>
</div>
```

```
#mainHeaderWrapper{
    position: relative;
    background: no-repeat url(path/to/image.jpg) 50% / 100%;
}
#mainHeaderWrapper > img{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%; /* max width */
    opacity: 0;  /* make it transparent */
}
#mainHeaderWrapper > div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was wondering how i was going to add content inside that div, so your second part of the answer has helped greatly.

Comment: Second part was just ROCK!

Comment: It really works but you will have problems in terms of a responsive website.

Answer (score 13):

If you know the proportions of the image, use percentage padding to define the height of the container. Set `height:0` and set vertical padding to a percentage of the width.

They key to this method is that percentage-based vertical padding is always related to width.

According to the [box model (w3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the **width** of the
> generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and
> 'padding-bottom'.

Below, the image is 400px X 200px, so the proportion of height to width is 1:2 and `padding-top` is set to 50%;

```css
#mainHeaderWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/400x200/');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainHeaderWrapper"></div>
stuff below the image
```

In another example, the image is 300px X 100px. The height is ⅓ of the width, so the `padding-top` is set to 33.33%:

```css
#mainHeaderWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top:33.33%;
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/300x100/');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainHeaderWrapper"></div>
stuff below the image
```

---

### Edit:

As prompted by Paulie_D, other content in the div must be positioned absolutely, demonstrated below. I suggest positioning these elements using percentages, as well.

```css
#mainHeaderWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 33.33%;
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/300x100/');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#inner_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainHeaderWrapper">
  <div id="inner_content">Hello World</div>
</div>
stuff below the image
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done without using a dummy image. I will use dimensions of an image I just worked with for example.

The dimensions of my image are 2880x1410. Simplify the dimensions -> 96/47 (I used this simple ratio calculator http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/). Once you have the simplified ratio, plug the height and width to the equation:

height: calc((100vw * W) / H); 
So mine would read: height: calc((100vw * 47) / 96);

No need to worry about the contents of the div either (unless they dont fit)

Comment: This looks like it's working well for me. I'm surprised this doesn't have more upvotes as it's a much cleaner and simpler solution than the ones above and it works when the container has content within it, not just when it's empty.

Comment: `height: calc((100vh * W) / H);` worked for me, I changed the `vw` to `vh`. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{ margin: 0; padding: 0}

#box1{
background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/);
background-size: cover; 
background-attachment: fixed; 
margin: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100vh; 
display: table;
}
h1{ color: #ffffff; font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif"; font-size: 38px; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <h1>Code Bluster BILU </h1>
 </div>
```